# Set Sharepoint online document columns filled by XML file

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, document, xml, file-metadata

Is there any way how to set metadata of specific document by XML file?

**For example**

We have OCR system which can store information about document in XML file (invoice number, supplier, date, etc.) and I want to take that XML -> upload it to the Sharepoint Online (or do it automatically by flow or something) -> pair that metadata with document (lookup by invoice number?).

You can even send me third-party add-ins but the solution with Sharepoint only (PowerShell, Flow, etc...) would be best.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution 1 (Third-party - paid)**

If third party solution is feasible, use Simego data synchronization studio https://www.simego.com/solutions/sharepoint-integration. You can setup xml file location to read xml files and set the target as SharePoint library. Finally schedule it in Windows Task Scheduler.

**Solution 2 (BCS - XML connector)**

BCS supports only SQL Server, WCF, .Net and OData source. So you need to create a XML connector to read xml data and store it in a SharePoint list. The brief outline is below and detail is [here](http://sharepointrapt.blogspot.com.au/2014/10/sharepoint-2013-custom-bcs-connector.html).

1. Create a Class Library project in Visual Studio.
2. Create a class and implement ISystemUtility interface from in Microsoft.BusinessData assembly.
3. Build the project and deploy the dll to GAC (c:\windows\assembly). Restart IIS
4. Create a BCS model and upload it to central admin.

Sample C# code for XML connector

```
public class XMLConnector : ISystemUtility 
{
    public void ExecuteStatic(IMethodInstance mi,
        ILobSystemInstance si,
        object[] args,
        IExecutionContext context)
    {

        switch (mi.MethodInstanceType)
        {
            //Single product view
            case MethodInstanceType.SpecificFinder:
                int id = (int)args[0];
                args[1] = GetProduct(id);
            break;
            //Product Listing
            case MethodInstanceType.Finder:
                args[args.Length - 1] = GetProducts();
            break;    
        }
    }
}
```

Sample BCS model

```
<Properties>
    <Property Type="System.String" Name="SystemUtilityTypeName">ClassLibraryProject.XMLConnector, ClassLibraryProject, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=3c36ccc14bfdf0d2
    </Property>
</Properties>

<LobSystemInstances>
    <LobSystemInstance Name="ItemsData">
        <Properties>
            <Property Name="xmlfilepath" Type="System.String">c:\testfolder\products.xml</Property>
        </Properties>
    </LobSystemInstance>
</LobSystemInstances>
```

**Solution 3 (custom code)**

Custom code like powershell or a console application.

Comment: OK thanks I will try it, but € 1,438.00 / Year is a lot. Small companies can't afford that.

Comment: @Sentir I have added solution 2 in my answer. Hope that helps.